# $.validator is undefined in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a very strange in an MVC app: I'm using the validate plugin of JQuery in order to enable client side validation using DTO Attributes.

The plugin works well, but when I try to get the "valiator" instance using $.validator, this last one is undefined!!!

I correctly load the three JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/HTMLClient/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/HTMLClient/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/HTMLClient/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I try to run this JS code:

```
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            onkeyup: false
        });
```

But here's the problem:

[image]

Comment: Please post the console output/error

Comment: Could it be that you importing validate.js to your page multiple times? I.e. check that it's only added once.

Comment: Make sure that you have no other html element with same id. Also make sure you have enabled unobtrusive AJAX in your web.config, otherwise the system will fallback to the legacy Microsoft ajax scripts:

`<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>`